# insert in two table with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I work with java and hibernate

I have probleme when I try to insert in two table 
I should insert in the first table  then insert in the second table

I have this java methode :

```
public RequestHealthCertificate updateHealthCertificate(String requestId, String requestStatusCode,String raisonRefus) {
        try{

        RequestStatusHealthLicense requestStatus = requestStatusHealthLicenseDaoImpl.getRequestStatusByCode(requestStatusCode);
        RequestHealthCertificate requestHealthCertificate= requestHealthCertificateDaoImpl.getHealthCertificateByNum(requestId);
        requestHealthCertificate.setRequestStatusHealthLicense(requestStatus);
        if(raisonRefus!=null &&!raisonRefus.equals("")){
            requestHealthCertificate.setNoAcceptedRaison(raisonRefus);
            }
        else {
            requestHealthCertificate.setNoAcceptedRaison(null);

        }
        HealthCertificate healthCertificateEntity = new HealthCertificate();
        healthCertificateEntity.setStartDateHc(new Date());
        Date dt = new Date();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        c.setTime(dt); 
        c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        dt = c.getTime();
        healthCertificateEntity.setEndDateHc(dt);
        healthCertificateEntity.setEndDateHjHc(this.convertDateMiladiToHijri(dt));
        healthCertificateEntity.setStartDateHjHc(this.convertDateMiladiToHijri(new Date()));
        String val= healthCertificateDaoImpl.save(healthCertificateEntity);
        HealthCertificate   healthCertificate = healthCertificateDaoImpl.getHealthCertificateById(val);     
        requestHealthCertificate.setHealthCertificate(healthCertificate);
        requestHealthCertificateDaoImpl.update(requestHealthCertificate);
        return requestHealthCertificate;
        }
        catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        }
    }
```

in my application  when I run this function I have this error :

```
20:10:56,713 ERROR [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8082-3) could not initialize proxy - no Session: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:191) [hibernate3.jar:3.5.3-Final]
    at com.dq.taif.licensing.hibernate.model.Citizen_$$_javassist_89.getIdentityCountryCti(Citizen_$$_javassist_89.java) [Taif_Data-dao-1.0.0.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
```

Comment: SHARE your hibernate code, and your POJO class

Comment: You don't have an active session. If this is a DAO method, add `@Transactional`